# Regular train service from Antananarivo to Antsirabe?

Tags: trains, madagascar

The Madarail website lists two options from [Antananarivo](https://en.wikivoyage.org/wiki/Antananarivo) to [Antsirabe](https://en.wikivoyage.org/wiki/Antsirabe):

- [La Micheline "Viko-Viko"](http://www.madarail.mg/voyages_trains_touristiques_micheline.php)
- [Le Trans Lemurie Express](http://www.madarail.mg/voyages_trains_touristiques_trans_lemurie.php)

Both options seem to run for weddings and such events, according to the description.
Also, the [French Wikivoyage](https://fr.wikivoyage.org/wiki/Madagascar#En_train) says the line is closed, but I don't know how recent the information is.

Is there any regular train service that individuals can use, more economical than hiring a whole train for yourself?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At [madarail.mg](http://www.madarail.mg) you can find an [overview of current routes](http://www.madarail.mg/voyages_train_voyageur.php).

Antananarivo and Antsirabe are not on it (September 2014).

Answer (score 5):

No, there is only cargo rail service between from Antananarivo to Antsirabe.

The only public transportation options are taxi-brousse and plane.

Answer (score 4):

As of August 2017, there are still no passenger train services from Antananarivo. (For a while, the vintage Micheline did run a tourist trip from Antananarivo at weekends, but it no longer operates any services.) Passenger trains in Madagascar run on at least one day per week on the following routes:

- Moramanga to Toamasina (Tamatave)
- Moramanga to Ambatondrazaka
- Fianarantsoa to Manakara

Each of these journies takes between half a day and one day.